# Problema al concatenar en una una consulta sql

Tags: php

Estoy intentando obtener el resultado de la siguiente consulta sql, pero no me da ningun resulta y e situado el problema en el final de la consulta cuando concateno la variable.

```php
$consulta = 'SELECT tipo.nombre AS tipo, recetas.id_tipo AS id_Tipo, usuarios.nombre AS usuarios, recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario, recetas.nombre AS recetas, recetas.id AS id_Receta, recetas.preparacion, recetas.fecha_creacion, recetas.imagen, recetas.inf_nutricional, recetas.ingredientes FROM tipo, usuarios, recetas WHERE recetas.id_tipo = tipo.id AND recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id AND recetas.nombre LIKE \'%' . $nombre . '%\'';
```

--- MODIFICACIÓN ---

Pongo la función entera

```php
function getByName($nombre) {
        $consulta = 'SELECT tipo.nombre AS tipo, recetas.id_tipo AS id_Tipo, usuarios.nombre AS usuarios, recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario, recetas.nombre AS recetas, recetas.id AS id_Receta, recetas.preparacion, recetas.fecha_creacion, recetas.imagen, recetas.inf_nutricional, recetas.ingredientes FROM tipo, usuarios, recetas WHERE recetas.id_tipo = tipo.id AND recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id AND recetas.nombre LIKE \'%' . $nombre . '%\'';
        $resultado = mysqli_query($this->conectar->getConexion(), $consulta);
        $array["items"] = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
            $arrayAsociativo = [
                "idTipo" => $row["id_Tipo"],
                "tipo" => $row["tipo"],
                "idUsuario" => $row["id_Usuario"],
                "usuario" => $row["usuarios"],
                "idReceta" => $row["id_Receta"],
                "receta" => $row["recetas"],
                "preparacion" => $row["preparacion"],
                "fechaCreacion" => $row["fecha_creacion"],
                "imagen" => $row["imagen"],
                "infNutricional" => $row["inf_nutricional"],
                "ingredientes" => $row["ingredientes"]
            ];

            array_push($array["items"], $arrayAsociativo);
        }

        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor resultante de `$consulta`?

Comment: @Sal la variable $consulta está dentro de una función ```function getByName($nombre) {...}```. Al ejecutar está función pasas como parámetro una palabra y en la consulta sql buscara todo los registros en la base de datos que contenga esa palabra y devolverá el resultado pero me está fallando a la hora de concatenar la variable en la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php), puedes hacer algo como:

```
$consulta = "SELECT  tipo.nombre AS tipo, recetas.id_tipo AS id_Tipo, usuarios.nombre AS usuarios, recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario, recetas.nombre AS recetas, recetas.id AS id_Receta, recetas.preparacion, recetas.fecha_creacion, recetas.imagen, recetas.inf_nutricional, recetas.ingredientes  FROM tipo, usuarios, recetas WHERE recetas.id_tipo = tipo.id AND recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id AND recetas.nombre LIKE :nombre "; 

$pdo = new PDO(...);
$smt_consulta = $pdo->prepare($consulta);
$smt_consulta->execute(array(':nombre' => '%'.$nombre.'%'));

$ar_result = smt_consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($ar_result as $r){
    echo $r['tipo'];
    ....
}
```

Con [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), puedes pasar la variable a la query de dos formas, la primera:

```
$consulta = "SELECT tipo.nombre AS tipo, recetas.id_tipo AS id_Tipo, usuarios.nombre AS usuarios, recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario, recetas.nombre AS recetas, recetas.id AS id_Receta, recetas.preparacion, recetas.fecha_creacion, recetas.imagen, recetas.inf_nutricional, recetas.ingredientes FROM tipo, usuarios, recetas WHERE recetas.id_tipo = tipo.id AND recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id AND recetas.nombre LIKE '%$nombre%'";
```

Y la segunda construyendo una variable:

```
$like_nombre = "%".$nombre."%"
$consulta = "SELECT tipo.nombre AS tipo, recetas.id_tipo AS id_Tipo, usuarios.nombre AS usuarios, recetas.id_usuario AS id_Usuario, recetas.nombre AS recetas, recetas.id AS id_Receta, recetas.preparacion, recetas.fecha_creacion, recetas.imagen, recetas.inf_nutricional, recetas.ingredientes FROM tipo, usuarios, recetas WHERE recetas.id_tipo = tipo.id AND recetas.id_usuario = usuarios.id AND recetas.nombre LIKE '$like_nombre'";
```

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($this->conectar->getConexion(), $consulta);
```

Comment: la conexión a la base de datos ya la tengo echa, lo que está fallando es la concatenación de la variable $nombre que es pasada como parámetro de la función, para la conexión ```$resultado = mysqli_query($this->conectar->getConexion(), $consulta);```.